# How to represent Binary Matrix with {0,1} bits as elements?

Tags: c, bit

I written an error correction code which uses a binary generator matrix(which i have declared and initialized within the code) in which each individual element in the matrix is declared as an int(as far as i understand that the size of int in xilix software development kit (XSDK) is 32, please correct me if am wrong). what i want to do is try to declare a binary matrix , that represents each element of the matrix as a bit rather than a word , to optimize the code , to improve space constraints in memory. Is there a bit type in XSDK. please advice. If not , please suggest if this can be achieved in any other way. I've attached my matrix declaration code. please check.

```
#define ROWS 102  //k
#define COLS 204
int main()
{    

int msg[ROWS];
int dout[COLS];
int G[ROWS][COLS] = {0};
int i,j,k,r,c,n;

 k = ROWS;
 r = ROWS;
 c = COLS;
 n = COLS;
 static int H[ROWS][COLS] = {0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1......};

int Codeword[COLS]= {0};
int s = 0;
for (i=0;i<k;i++)
for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    if(i == j)
    G[i][j] = 1;

for(i=0;i<r;i++)
for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    G[j][k+i] = H[i][j];

for(i=0;i<r;i++)
   {
for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    printf("%d",G[i][j]);
   }

for(j=0;j<n;j++)
 {
 for(i=0;i<k;i++)
 {
    s = s + msg[i]*G[i][j];
 }
Codeword[j] = s % 2;
s = 0;
 }
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
printf("%d",Codeword[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: There is no "bit" type in C, the smallest addressable object is `char`. If you need to store the bit matrix as actual bits, you need to write the corresponding code, but it might be slower than an implementation where each bit is represented as a char.

Comment: Thank you . yeah that makes sense. although am specifically enquiring for  vivado HLS. to optimize implementation on hardware.

Comment: as my matrix in [204]*[102], it would be 20808 elements ,each representing a word.  it is a binary matrix , so i was wondering if there is any possibilities of representing the elements as bits? thanks

Comment: You atleast save space in column, but mapping each element to a column index and a bit position. column index = elem / 8 , bit_index = elem % 8;